# Private REST API connection Power BI (M - Power Query)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, bearer-token, rest, m

I'd like to connect powerbi with client private Rest APi. So, I've been trying to write the code in M in order to do it, but I am not an expert in M language.

This is what I've tried to generarte the Bearer Token inside Power bi. Can you help me with the code?

```
  let
    url = "https://openid-provider.crearesistemas.com.br/auth/v1/token?lang=pt-BR",
    body  = "{ ""client_id"": ""*****"",  ""client_secret"": ""*****"", ""grant_type"": ""client_credentials""}",

    tokenResponse = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,
    [Headers = [#"Authorization"="Basic Auth", #"Content-Type"="application/json"
    ],
     Content = Text.ToBinary(body)
    ] 
    )),
    AccessToken = tokenResponse[access_token],
    AccessTokenHeader = "Bearer " & AccessToken
in 
AccessTokenHeader
```

I don't know what I've done wrong.
It shows the following error: "DataSource.Error" "DataSourceKind=Web" "DataSourcePath=https://openid-provider.crearesistemas.com.br/auth/v1/token"

After generate the Bearer Token, I must use the 'get method' in order to request clients data from the api.
main_api_url: https://api.crearecloud.com.br/frotalog/basic-services/v3/ ...
Authorization: Bearer Token
Json format

I hope you guy can help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to do the API call without `#"Authorization"="Basic Auth"`?
Have you tried the same in `Postman` or similar?

Comment: Hi Angelo, in postman it works fine. I've tried as well: #"Authorization"="Basic".

Comment: And without that parameter? What kind of status code error do you receive?

Comment: The same error. 

"DataSource.Error: Há suporte para Web.Contents com a opção Content somente durante uma conexão anônima.
Detalhes:
    DataSourceKind=Web
    DataSourcePath=https://openid-provider.crearesistemas.com.br/auth/v1/token"

Comment: Hard to tell, Power BI is not very descriptive in those errors. What kind of status code do you receive? `401`, `500`? You could use something like `Wireshark` to see what's the problem with your query.

Comment: There is no error  code.

Answer (score 1):

It helps if you link the docs to the endpoint you are trying to use, otherwise we don't know exactly what you need. What HTTP requests are your goal?

> I must use the 'get method'

For a `GET` request you use `Query`, for `POST` you use `Content`. Both accept `type record`

## Input

For step 1 I think you're asking for these arguments as a GET request.
If you need a POST, just replace `Query` with `Content`

```
using the example 
    "GET" request and:
    "https://openid-provider.crearesistemas.com.br/auth/v1/token?lang=pt-BR",
    {
        "client_id": "*****", 
        "client_secret": "*****",
        "grant_type": "client_credentials"
    }
```

## Power Query

```
let

    Headers = [
        Accept="application/json",
        Authorization = "Basic Auth"
    ],
    BaseUrl = "https://openid-provider.crearesistemas.com.br",
    Options = [
        RelativePath = "/auth/v1/token",
        Headers = Headers,
        Query = [
            lang = "pt-BR",
            client_id = "id",
            client_secret = "secret",
            grant_type = "client_credentails"
        ],
        ManualStatusHandling = {400, 404}
    ],
    // wrap 'Response' in 'Binary.Buffer' if you are referencing it multiple times
    response_binary = Web.Contents(BaseUrl, Options),
    buffered = Binary.Buffer(response_binary),
    response_metadata = Value.Metadata(response_binary),
    status_code = response_metadata[Response.Status],

    // for 400 and 404, return extra error info
    maybe_bytes =
        if List.Contains({400, 404}, status_code)
        then response_metadata else buffered,
    from_json = Json.Document(maybe_bytes)
    // returns either document else web request error
in
    from_json
```

See More:

- [Web.Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents)
- [A Custom function to simplify `Web.Contents` calls](https://github.com/ninmonkey/Ninmonkey.PowerQueryLib/blob/b747760fa4534c428829774776be10e05d25c853/source/WebRequest.pq)

Comment: Hi ninMOnkey, 

The endpoint in this case is: https://api.crearecloud.com.br/frotalog/basic-services/v3/vehicles |
Authorization: Bearer Token. |

When I first posted this, I was trying to first generate the bearer token inside powerbi in order to use the get method. This is my first time using an API.

Comment: Now, I've tried with your code and shows pretty much the same error I got before. It says that I cannot use Authorization as header using Web. Content.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was getting dataflow refresh data before they made an API for it. Ideally, a person wouldn't put credentials in the query.

```
let
    APIString =" https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/gr...​",
    GetToken = 
    let
        client_id = yourclientID,
        client_secret= yourclientsecret,
        redirect_uri = "http://localhost:13526/redirect",
        token_uri = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token", 
        authorize_uri = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize",
        resource="https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
        username=yourusername,
        password=yourpassword,
        tokenResponse = Json.Document(Web.Contents(token_uri, [Content = Text.ToBinary(Uri.BuildQueryString( [
                                            client_id = client_id
                                            ,client_secret=client_secret
                                            ,username=username
                                            ,password=password
                                            ,resource=resource
                                            ,grant_type = "password"
                                            ,redirect_uri = redirect_uri ])), Headers= [Accept="application/json"]
                                            ,ManualStatusHandling= {400} ])),
        access_token = tokenResponse[access_token],
        token = tokenResponse[access_token]
    in
        token,
    GetGroups = Json.Document(Web.Contents(APIString, [ Headers = [ Authorization="Bearer "& GetToken ], ManualStatusHandling={400} ] )),
    value = GetGroups[value],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(value, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id", "refreshType", "startTime", "endTime", "status"}, {"id", "refreshType", "startTime", "endTime", "status"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Column1",{{"id", type text}, {"refreshType", type text}, {"status", type text}, {"startTime", type datetimezone}, {"endTime", type datetimezone}}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type",{{"endTime", type datetime}, {"startTime", type datetime}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

Comment: + @Bruno Fantinelli If you use the web.contents parameter `ApiKeyName` and set it to what the API expects, the GUI will let you store credentials in the credential store instead of the query itself. If you don't see it, is near connection properties and privacy. If you pick anonymous then you end up with credentials in your query -- or report parameter.